# Updating code from one command line argument to two

Tags: c++, command-line

I have code which does the following :

```
const char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "stuff.jpg";
```

which reads in a photo as a command line argument and displays it.

I now want to take in two photo's, I tried this code :

```
const char* filename = argc >= 3 ? argv[1] : "stuff.jpg", argv[2] : "tester.jpg";
```

But I get an error like this :

```
error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
```

Anybody know whats wrong? is there a similer way to do this input programmatically?

Comment: I you want to handle 2 photos you probably need two different 'filename' variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with a ternary if-operator here. Have a look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a). It's basically an inline if-statement.

Code that would do what you're looking for, looks something a little like this:

```
const char* filename1 = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : "stuff.jpg";
const char* filename2 = argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : "tester.jpg";
```

That leaves you with two filename variables, storing either the supplied argument or the default values (`stuff.jpg` and `tester.jpg`, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

To get all the arguments in an easy to use format I do:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string>   args(&argv[1], &argv[argc]);

    // args.size() is the number of arguments.
    //             In your case the number of files.
    //             So now you can just loop over the file names and display each one.

    // Note The above is guranteed to be OK
    // As argv[] will always have a minimum of 2 members.
    //   argv[0]    is the command name           thus argc is always >= 1
    //   argv[argc] is always a NULL terminator.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you need 4, 5, or more photos?
Pseudo code:

```
 vector<char *> photos;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
       for i to argc-1
          photos.push_back(argv[i]) ;
    }
```